# How to use "find" command to get files created yesterday?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I m running a batch file that gets a list of all files and subfolders under a directory. then I will filter out some specific files created today and yesterday from that list. I have some difficulty of finding file created yesterday, I thought maybe `%date% - 1` may work but it doesn't. Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks

```
REM SETUP CREATE TIME
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6%


REM LIST OF FILES AND FOLDERS

dir /s "K:\AppData\Released_To_Production" > "C:\K_RLTP_FILES.txt"
dir /a:d /t:w /s "K:\AppData\Released_To_Production" > "C:\K_RLTP_Folders.txt"

REM TODAY'S CATIA FILES

echo List is Created @  [%ldt%] > "C:\catia_result.txt"
echo -------------------------------------------- >> "C:\catia_result.txt"
echo -------------------------------------------- >> "C:\catia_result.txt"
find ".model" "C:\K_RLTP_FILES.txt" | find "%date%" >> "C:\catia_result.txt"
find ".CATPart" "C:\K_RLTP_FILES.txt" | find "%date%" >> "C:\catia_result.txt"
```

Comment: take a look at `forfiles /?`

Comment: I am trying to filter lines with yesterday's date in a txt, I dont think forfiles can be used here.....

Comment: well - not directly. But thinking around some corners can help. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
REM get all files older than 5 days:
forfiles /s /d -5 /c:"cmd /c echo @path" >a.txt
REM get all files:
forfiles /s /c:"cmd /c echo @path" >b.txt
REM get all files minus files older than 5 days:
findstr /v /g:a.txt b.txt
```

Note: I choosed 5 days for testing. For files changed today and yesterday you'll have to use `-1` instead of `-5`

Comment: Thanks for help. this maybe be easier than finding out yesterday's date.

Comment: This will include any files created today. Any way to avoid that also?